Websocket push using Gglgen library for graphQL subscriptions - high latencies
We have a golang service which manages websocket connections with web frontend and for that we are using graphQL subscriptions, where web frontend creates graphQL subscriptions and any updates to the subscriptions.
We are using gqlgen library for that,
github - https://gqlgen.com/recipes/subscriptions/
documentation - https://gqlgen.com/recipes/subscriptions/
we are observing performance issues like writing to subscriptions is taking time becoming bottleneck for us.
we are creating a buffered channel of size 1 and this channel is returned from subscriptionResolver which is used by the library to send messages to client.
msgc := make(chan *updatepb.Update, 1)
Are there known issues with this library around its performance to be used as websocket?
what could be the alerternative for this? Does increasing channel size would help?
We will try to increase the channel size to see if it helps but what is the recommendation?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
